# displaying dropdown menu and checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, dropdown

I am trying to make a database program for my dad, where he can use drop down menus to select movies or shows. When starting the program, there is a checkbox asking the user if they are "rikkefied"(little inside joke)

I came quite far with the code, but when excecuting it it just returns exit code 0, without displaying the checkbox or the dropdowns. What did I forget?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import StringVar

class WelcomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.check_rikkefied()

    def check_rikkefied(self):
        #show message box with "Yes and "NO" buttons
        answer= messagebox.askyesno("Rikkefication check", "Are you rikkefied")
        if answer:
            self.create_widgets()
        else: self.master.destroy()
    def create_widgets(self):
        #create the labels for the dropdown menu
        title_label = tk.Label(self, text="Title")
        genre_label = tk.Label(self, text = "Genre")
        actor_label = tk.Label(self, text="Actor")
        type_label = tk.Label(self, text="Movie / Show")
        country_label = tk.Label(self, text="Country")
        decade_label = tk.Label(self, text = "Released in")

        #create the dropdown menus
        with open('movie_title.txt') as f:
            movie_titles= [line.strip () for line in f.readlines()]
        title_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        title_var.set("Movie Title")
        title_dropdown =tk.OptionMenu(self, title_var, *movie_titles, command= self.show.movie_info)

        with open('actors_list.txt') as f:
            actor_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
        actor_var=tk.StringVar(self)
        actor_var.set("Actor")
        actor_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, actor_var, *actor_list, command= self.show.actor_info)

        genre_var= StringVar(self)
        genre_var.set("Genre")
        genre_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, genre_var, "Action", "Animation","Drama", "Fantasy", "Historical", "Comedy", "War", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller", "Westrern")

        with open('country_list.txt') as f:
            country_list =[line.strip () for line in f.readlines()]
        country_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        country_var.set("Country")
        country_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, country_var, *country_list, command= self.show.country_info)

        decade_var=StringVar(self)
        decade_var.set("Released in ")
        decade_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self, decade_var, "1940's", "1950's", "1960's", "1970's", "1980's", "1990's", "2000's", "2020's", "2030's")

        type_var = StringVar(self)
        type_var.set("Movie / TV ")
        type_dropdown= tk.OptionMenu(self, type_var, "Movie", "TV Show")


        #create checkbox
        checkbox_var=tk.BooleanVar(self)
        checkbox_var.set(False)
        checkbox= tk.Checkbutton(self, text= "Rikkefication", variable=checkbox_var)

        #use the pack methiod to add the labels and dropdowns to the frame
        title_label.pack()
        title_dropdown.pack()
        genre_label.pack()
        genre_dropdown.pack()
        actor_label.pack()
        actor_dropdown.pack()
        type_label.pack()
        type_dropdown.pack()
        country_label.pack()
        country_dropdown.pack()
        decade_label.pack()
        decade_dropdown.pack()
        checkbox.pack()
```

I created the labels and widgets for the drop down menus, I made .txt files and saved them in the same directory. I used the pack() method to attach it to the frame.

Comment: You aren't creating a root window, an instance of `WelcomePage`, or calling mainloop. All of that is required.

Comment: See [ask]. You need to research more. There are tones of Tkinter tutorials. See [this](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#building-your-first-python-gui-application-with-tkinter) for example.